# Android devices are unable to connect to Rogue Acces point created using Airbase-ng

Tags: network, wifi, android, dhcp, aircrack-ng

I have created a rogue access point using airbase-ng, but I can't connect to it using my android phones (note II, S4), when I tap on the access point all I get is: Obtaining IP address...', than disconnects and it tries again and again. I would really appreciate some help, I am quite new to linux...:(

In the terminal I see the same output:

```
10:43:58  Created tap interface at0
10:43:58  Trying to set MTU on at0 to 1500
10:43:58  Trying to set MTU on wlan0 to 1800
10:43:58  Access Point with BSSID 7A:44:AF:F6:04:C8 started.
10:46:03  Client 5C:F8:A1:40:5F:F0 associated (unencrypted) to ESSID: "default"
10:46:13  Client 5C:F8:A1:40:5F:F0 associated (unencrypted) to ESSID: "default"
10:46:23  Client 5C:F8:A1:40:5F:F0 associated (unencrypted) to ESSID: "default"
10:46:34  Client 5C:F8:A1:40:5F:F0 associated (unencrypted) to ESSID: "default"
10:46:49  Client 5C:F8:A1:40:5F:F0 associated (unencrypted) to ESSID: "default"
10:46:49  Client 5C:F8:A1:40:5F:F0 associated (unencrypted) to ESSID: "default"
```

steps I am doing:

1.) create the fake WiFi access point using airbase-n:

```
airbase-ng  wlan0
```

2.) alocating IP and Subnet:

```
ifconfig at0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

3.) start DHCP server

```
service isc-dhcp-server start
```

my dhcpd.conf contains the following:

```
authoritative;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
{
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.5.255;
        option routers 192.168.5.1;
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
        range 192.168.5.1 192.168.5.100;
}
```

systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service tells the following:

```
    isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-03-03 12:32:51 EET; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3803 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]: ** Ignoring requests on wlan1.  If this is not what
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]:    to which interface wlan1 is attached. **
Mar 03 12:32:51 kali isc-dhcp-server[3803]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Mar 03 12:32:51 kali isc-dhcp-server[3803]: failed!
Mar 03 12:32:51 kali systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 03 12:32:51 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Mar 03 12:32:51 kali systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 03 12:32:51 kali systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.152.187.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan1
  iface wlan1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right in the logs:

```
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]: ** Ignoring requests on wlan1.  If this is not what
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Mar 03 12:32:49 kali dhcpd[3813]:    to which interface wlan1 is attached. **
```

Your wlan1 interface is on `192.168.1.0` network, and you are trying to start a DHCP server on `192.168.5.0`. Change that and it will work.

You are learning Linux, so remember this: **ALWAYS** read the logs. They will (usually) tell you what is wrong, what was expected and what you should change.